# Display All Frames List for any WebPage

Tags: javascript, loops, iframe, recursion, frame

I want to create a **recursive JavaScript loop** which can display all the **Frames** (either using IFRAMES Tag or using FRAME Tag). The result should give FrameName, NestingLevel, FrameURL, etc.

For example, when we open 'Developer Tools' in Google Chrome, we can see in all the FRAMES(even nested Frames too) in the console tab.
[image: Image showing list for Frames using GoogleChrome is shown here for the reference]

Please give a recursive loop with error handling (iframe security issue) for the same.!

**Sample Code**:

```
function getFramesInfo(oWin) {
  arrFrames = oWin.frames;
  //alert(arrFrames.length);
  if (arrFrames.length == 0) {
    alert('document do not have frame(s)');
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < arrFrames.length; i++) {
      console.log(i + ' ' + arrFrames[i].location.href);
      if (arrFrames[i].document) {
        getFramesInfo(arrFrames[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
//Calling This Function
getFramesInfo(window);
```

Comment: did you try something? or `give` is the first thing that apperas in your mind?

Comment: yes I tried something like,

var arrFrames = top.frames;
for(i=0;i<arrFrames.length;i++){alert(i+' '+arrFrames[i].location.href)}

Comment: so next step is to describe what's wrong with this code, do you got errors ... and ask the question in proper way "I have done this ... I have this error, I can not understand why " ... or similar way ...

Comment: I do not know how to debug the error. please see the attached code in the question and try to correct it (even for cross-domain errors, etc.)

Comment: Error is Texed as **Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame**. Please add code for Error Handling

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate / Improved Code**:

```
function getAllFrames(frame, allFrameArray) {
  allFrameArray.push(frame.frames);
  for (var i = 0; i < frame.frames.length; i++) {
    getAllFrames(frame.frames[i], allFrameArray);
  }
  return allFrameArray;
}
//Usage:

var allFramesArray = getAllFrames(window, new Array());
console.log(allFramesArray.length); // number of frames in array
for (var i = 0; i < allFramesArray.length; i++) {
  console.log('\n\n No.'+ (i+1) + '.');
  try {
    console.log(allFramesArray[i].id);
    console.log(allFramesArray[i].name);
    console.log(allFramesArray[i].location.href); // location of first frame in array}
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in Accessing Frame No.' + (i+1) ); // location of first frame in array}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling and exploring I have found a simple solution, but I think this answer should be improved to avoid any possible errors (*i.e. precise error handling should be done to avoid cross-domain frames issue*):

**Sample Solution**:

```
// first parameter is frame (window) in which to get sub frames
// second is the array to build on
function getAllFrames(frame, allFrameArray) {
  allFrameArray.push(frame.frames);
  for (var i = 0; i < frame.frames.length; i++) {
    getAllFrames(frame.frames[i], allFrameArray);
  }
  return allFrameArray;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var allFramesArray = getAllFrames(window, new Array());
console.log(allFramesArray.length); // number of frames in array
for (var i = 0; i < allFramesArray.length; i++) {
  try {
    console.log(allFramesArray[i].location.href); // location of first frame in array}
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in Accessing Frame No.' + i); // location of first frame in array}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another one** (shortcut example)

```
  var i = new Array;

  function wow(a, n) {
    t = '';
    for (i[n] = 0; i[n] < a.length; i[n]++) {
      try {
        t += a[i[n]].name + ' \n';
      } catch (e) {
        t += 'Error \n';
      }
      if (a[i[n]].frames.length) t += wow(a[i[n]].frames, n + 1);

    }
    return t;
  }

  //Usage:
  console.log(wow(top.frames, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

While browsing for a code, I recently have learnt a new code, using this code which takes a **javascript** window object as input and **returns all its nested windows** (including multiple levels of nesting). This function however is an efficient/elegant way that can be used to grab a reference to all the windows (objects) and all the child windows (objects). I have checked this function and found that it works well, it could be understood that making/writing this function completely recursively, as the DOM object tree is actually an n-ary, not binary.

```
function getAllNestedWindows(window) {
    var windows = [window];
    if (window.length === 0) {
        return windows;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < window.length; i++) {
            windows = windows.concat(getAllNestedWindows(window[i]));
        }
    }
    return windows;
}
```